# Correct term for the set of numbers which cannot be expressed in a particular base

Tags: terminology

For every base there's a set of fractions that can't be expressed with the exponent in that base, for instance 1/3 cannot be represented in decimal and 1/10 can't be represented in binary (particularly relevant to floating-point calculations in computers).

I've heard these described as *irrational*, but I think that's incorrect (although the true *irrational* set will be contained in this set for any base).

What is the correct term (if there is one)?

Comment: What you're asking about is rational numbers with a finite expansion in some base $b$. I'm a bit tired so I don't have time to work through all the details. But I think it's something along the lines of $1/n$ has a finite decimal representation in base $b$ if and only if for ever prime $p$ dividing $n$ then $p$ also divides $b$.

Comment: @JacobSchlather - cheers, I'd kind of just assumed that bit (that every base has this set), but what I'd like to know is whether there's a term for it.

Comment: It's called finite decimal (or base b) expansion. Like 1/3 is a rational, but doesn't have a finite decimal expansion. You can show that regardless of the base, a number is rational IFF it can be expressed as a finite or repeating decimal.

Comment: I don't know of any special term. Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/126313/1930) Arturo Magidin proves the characterization I mentioned.

Comment: Since the property depends on the choice of base $b$, it is somewhat "uninteresting" and that's probably why there is no established name.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen quite possibly, unless you're a programmer and this set is something that you have to deal with every day :-S

Comment: @CalvinLin so the term for fractions that can't be expressed in base 2 would be something like _numbers outside the finite binary expansion_?

Comment: @Keith, more like "numbers without a finite binary expansion."